# Who are the past Buddhas mentioned in the Canonical Works?

Tags: pali-canon, buddhas

What references do we have in canonical texts on historical Buddhas and Pacceka Buddhas? Ideally including information beyond the commonly referenced [28 Buddhas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_twenty-eight_Buddhas).

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Yeah, I'm confused too. Seems like a perfectly cogent question, as evidenced at very least by catpnosis's equally cogent answer (not to say I agree or disagree with cat ... I have no idea about this matter). Upvoting (albeit only back to zero)

Answer (score 2):

"Historical" is fact established by historical science. Even historical existence of Shakyamuni is debated. There is no other *historical* buddhas besides Shakyamuni. That is other buddhas are present to us only as *mythological* characters.